# Removing a Firefox web extension does not clear chrome.storage.local

Tags: local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

Looks like `chrome.storage.local` is continuing to store any data even if an extension was uninstalled.
This behaviour  is not observed in Chrome, only in Firefox.

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: Clear storage onInstalled?

Comment: Is your issue that the extension you are writing ends up having `chrome.storage.local` not be empty upon re-installation? Or, is it that you have some extension which you have installed (that you did not write) which has left content in `chrome.storage.local`?

Comment: Hi Guys! Thanks for comments.
To Daniel Herr:
As I know - for current moment Firefox webextensions not supported onInstalled method(...
to Makyen:
first case, described by you

Answer (score 1):

This was [bug 1213990](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1213990), which is fixed in Firefox 51.

Comment: Hi Andrew Swan. Thanks for response.
Is the localStorage, described in this bug - the same with chrome.storage.local?
By my information - these are different essencies.. But I can be wrong.

Comment: The fix for that bug addressed storage.local as well as dom storage interfaces including localStorage, indexedDB, etc.