# Clear storage.local outside of WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

How to clear `storage.local` outside the WebExtension code without uninstalling the WebExtension?

Inside the WebExtension, [`storage.local.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Storage/StorageArea/clear) [could be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clear-localstorage?rq=1). [On uninstall, `storage.local` is cleared as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117890/removing-of-firefox-web-extension-not-clear-chrome-storage-local).

Is there another way to remove either the WebExtension's `storage.local` or all of it? (Either in the browser console, the command line or ...?)

Comment: `Outside`? You can delete the storage file in FF profile folder, I guess.

Comment: `browser-extension-data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments:

> You can delete the storage file in FF profile folder [... named]
>   `browser-extension-data`